# Javascript equivalent of Python's iterkeys() dictionary method

Tags: javascript, python

In Python I can use the `iterkeys()` method to iterate over the keys of a dictionary. For example:

```
mydict = {'a': [3,5,6,43,3,6,3,],
          'b': [87,65,3,45,7,8],
          'c': [34,57,8,9,9,2],}
for k in mydict.iterkeys():
    print k
```

gives me:

```
a
c
b
```

How can I do something similar in Javascript?

Comment: Usually it's ok to just use `for k in mydict:` to iterate over the keys in Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var mydict = {
  'a': [3,5,6,43,3,6,3,],
  'b': [87,65,3,45,7,8],
  'c': [34,57,8,9,9,2],
};
for (var key in mydict) {
  alert(key);
}
```

Comment: That was easy. I feel dumb. Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, you should check if the key is one of the object's own properties as opposed to one derived from `Object`. Use `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(k in mydict){
   alert(k)
}
```